# Search a hash when its values are arrays themselves

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash where my projects are each tagged with various codes.

```
@projects =
{
    "Project A" => ["2","4","11"],
    "Project B" => ["2","3","4"],
    "Project C" => ["2","5","11"]
}
```

How can I search for the projects attached to a specific tag, i.e. input `"4"` and we get `["Project A","Project B"]`.
  I've tried the standard value search method but it only works if the entire array is input, not any element within any array.

This isn't as important but would it be possible to search by multiple tags, i.e. input `["2","11"]`, and we get `["Project A","Project C"]`?

Comment: If you want this to be fast and it will be queried more often than built, you may want to consider storing the reverse index, e.g. `{"4" => ["Project A", "Project B"]}` at build time. Multiple tags would then just be the intersection (`&`) of the resulting value arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def search array, elem
  array.select{|key, value| value.include? elem}
end
```

and:

```
def search_many array, *elems
  elems.map{|elem| search array, elem}.flatten.uniq
end
```

Comment: Hi Andre - I'm looking for the keys alone, not the pairs, so add `.keys` to your answer and it's ready to go :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution to part I:

```
code_2s = @projects.collect{|k,v| (v.include? "2") ? k : nil }.compact
```